# Call a Angular js page in Play framework

Tags: angularjs, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am finding trouble to display my AngularJs page from Play framework 2.2

The Angular js page is located in the same project directory which is

> C:\webProj\test\app\www\index.html

**Note** *this index.html is not the index.scala.html that we have in play views directory*

I need to render this page from my Play project.
I have tried this

> GET          /masterid    controller.Assets.at("/app/www/",index.html)

but it gives a compilation error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it faster, just place your file in i.e.: `/public/angular-app/index.html`, so you can use it via:

```
@routes.Assets.at("angular-app/index.html")
```

Next (assuming that you have standard routes) you can just use static paths to your public assets, i.e. if image is placed in folder `public/img/logo.png` you can access it with:

```
<img src="/assets/img/logo.png" alt=""/>
```

So just by replacing `public/` to `/assets/` (slash at beginning to make sure you don't need to use `base` tag in head of document).

Comment: @thanks Biesior..I did that and works fine. I can render my page pretty well. but the page comes without images and js script loaded.Do i need to change src="img/logo.png" to src="@routes.Assets.at(public/img/logo.png)" and change the page from html to scala.html?

Answer (score 1):

### Explanation of the error

There are some syntax errors in this route configuration:

```
GET /masterid controller.Assets.at("/app/www/",index.html)
```

It should be `controllers` instead of controller, the path is wrong, and the parameters are not specified correctly. It could be written as:

```
GET /masterid controllers.Assets.at(path="/app/www", file="index.html")
```

Note that as written, this route will map **only** to the `index.html` file, not to any other resources under `/masterid`.

### Solution with a separate directory

To behave exactly as asked, with a separate directory and a custom URL, you would need to specity a second asset route in addition to the default one. This would also require changing all usages of `@routes.Assets.at` to specify two parameters (`folder` and `file`), and adding a configuration to `build.sbt`:

```
playAssetsDirectories <+= baseDirectory / "app/www"
```

### Solution using the public directory and a custom URL

The path of least resistance is to create the custom `index.html` file in the project's `public` directory. To use a custom URL as asked in the question, you could change the default asset path to "masterid" by changing this line in the `routes` file:

```
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

to this:

```
GET     /masterid/*file             controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

In this case the custom `index.html` file could be accessed as:

```
http://localhost:9000/masterid/index.html
```

Relative URLs to other resources under the `/public` folder would work as well.

### Solution using the public directory and the default URL

If you don't require the `/masterid` URL under the root, you can save your `index.html` file under `public/app` and refer to it as:

```
@routes.Assets.at("app/index.html")
```

This will resolve to:

```
http://localhost:9000/assets/app/index.html
```

### Documentation

For more extensive instructions see [Working with public assets](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/Assets).

Comment: thanks of answer @fernando. I tried the solution that you mentioned. But in this case if we change the base directory then other pages that are designed in Play starts showing compilation error as they are compiled for another play base directory. I suspect if it is possible to set multiple base directories?

Comment: That's true. I mention that in the answer. If you want to have two different paths, you need to add `playAssetsDirectories` to build.sbt and to change the parameters of `routes.Assets.at` calls. That's why I recommend using the predefined `public` directory. In any case don't forget to check the documentation. It can be a bit complex to understand at first but it explains all the possibilities.

Comment: @thanks again.. and yes it's a problem. I have 95% of pages developed in play and 5% of pages are specially developed using Angularjs so I guess I have to go with the solution @ biesor mentioned below.. but yes your solution works as well.

Comment: If you don't require the `masterid` URL, that is indeed the easiest solution. Anyway, I've updated my answer to better clarify the alternatives, because this may help other people in the future.